# Finding Unicode script of a Char in Haskell

Tags: haskell, unicode

I wanted to write a function checking that a `Char` represents a Cyrillic letter, purely for pedagogical reasons. The simple approximation for Russian is

```
isCyrillic c = 
    let lc = toLower c 
    in 'а' <= lc && lc <= 'я'
```

but I don't like it because it doesn't handle other Cyrillic-using languages. I could hardcode the ranges:

```
U+0400–U+04FF Cyrillic
U+0500–U+052F Cyrillic Supplement
U+2DE0–U+2DFF Cyrillic Extended-A
U+A640–U+A69F Cyrillic Extended-B
U+1C80–U+1C8F Cyrillic Extended-C
```

but this doesn't seem good practice either.

Ideally the function would be just

```
isCyrillic c = unicodeScript c == Cyrillic
```

but this assumes the existence of a type enumerating Unicode scripts (Unicode ranges would do as well). Is there one somewhere?

Comment: With respect to the resource request close votes, I feel there should be some leeway for standard-library-esque things (such as date-and-time or Unicode). I'd also say that is particularly relevant in the specific case of Haskell, whose actual standard library is, relatively speaking, quite narrowly scoped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`property`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-icu-0.7.0.1/docs/Data-Text-ICU-Char.html#v:property) from *text-icu*'s `Data.Text.ICU.Char` seems to fit the bill:

```
import Data.Text.ICU.Char

isCyrilic c = property Block c == Cyrillic
```